# Google Keyboard number row

Tags: gboard

I noticed in Google Keyboard that a dedicated number row appears when entering into a password field, but not when entering into any other field.

[image: Regular Field Input]
[image: Password Field Input]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

I have done some research and found guides that claim to do this, but instead they show to create a custom input style with a PC keyboard layout. While this results in permanently adding the number row at the top, it also changes the rest of the keyboard, which I would like to avoid.

[image: PC keyboard layout]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

I would like this row to be there for any field, not just password fields, without changing the rest of the keyboard. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to settings, Security and then check Unknown sources. You have to remove any previous versions of Google keyboard so go to Settings, Application Manager and go over to Google Keyboard. If you are using a Nexus device then you will need root privileges. Download the modified Google keyboard from here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2657791 After installation click open to enter settings or open the app from the app drawer. Configure the keyboard then set it as your default in settings.

Link:
http://www.techaudible.org/how-to-add-dedicated-numbers-row-to-native-google-keyboard/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems that the specific app you linked to is  a pretty old version of the Google keyboard and development on it has seized. The thread links to a new project that is under active development: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/lollipop-keyboard-phones-root-t2910268

Comment: Glad that I could help. I hope that the new app works for you.